# How do I display all the lines that contains the card number?

Tags: c#, database, foreach

Right now this is just presenting a line of the database but I need to present more, if anyone knew how to help me i would be grateful

```
private static string extratoOperacao(string numeroCartao)
{
    return getExtrato($@"SELECT CardNumber, Deposit, Withdraw, DataHora FROM MoveInfo WHERE CardNumber = '{numeroCartao}'");
}
private static string getExtrato(string query)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAD-PC-023\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bank;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = query })
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (reader.Read() == true)
            {
                    if (reader.GetString(1) == null)
                    {
                        return "\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " levantou: " + reader.GetString(2) + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " depositou: " + reader.GetString(1) + " euros " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3);
                    }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The supposed is to show all the information of the lines where the card number is equal to the inserted

Comment: correct syntax* (translator)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays This shows the syntax for foreach. However, we have no idea what the "getExtrato" method is doing, so we can't be of more help.

Comment: @tutiplain already edited, I've put what it does, I'll see if I can solve, thanks for the link

Comment: You probably don't need a foreach loop for this.  You are using ExecuteReader() which should be able to iterate through the results. You can keep calling the reader.Read() method to get the next row.

Comment: There is little reason to manually mess around with a `DataReader` these days, unless as a learning exercise, or because you need to squeeze out the last bit of performance. Otherwise you're better off using Dapper to handle this boilerplate.

Comment: @tutiplain is reading the first line, how do I present the necessary times? (sorry for being annoying :/)

Comment: instead of doing: if (reader.Read() ) { ... }  , do this: 
while (reader.Read() ) { ... }

Comment: @tutiplain still doesn't work but thanks, it must be something I'm not seeing.

Comment: continues to show only the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement is going to exit your function, which is why you only get one result. If you want multiple lines, you're going to need to build and return a collection (e.g., array, list, etc.) or use `yield return` . . . the collection is probably the most straight-forward approach.

If you want all of the results in a single string, you'll need `StringBuilder`.